# How to read file in resources folder

Tags: java, embedded-resource

Java and IntelliJ newbie here.Apologies if this has been answered already but I cannot seem to find the answer.

My project structure is that shown below:

[image: project]

I am trying to work out how to read the contents of the highllighted storedQueries.txt file as a single string. This must be simple and I've tried a number of methods involving getClass and so on, but nothing has worked thus far. Would appreciate any guidance, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file using current class loader but before that, you need to straighten up the structure a bit. When you use ClassLoader to read file, by default it looks into the same package it belongs to.

Step 1: Create new package `com.pe.queries` 
Step 2: Create the class `Package-Info.java` in above package 
Step 3: Create new nested directories under `resources` as `resources/com/pe/queries` and move the file to this directory. 
Step 4: Finally you should be able to read the file as
`Package-Info.class.getResource("storedQueries.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

```
getClass().getResource("/resources/etc.txt")
```

Put the resource folder inside target

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how you can get your resource:

1. By **absolute** path, but itsn't good way, cause absolute paths are unreliable, but it is good for 'smoke'-testing
2. By **relative** path, and there are two ways again.

In both ways you can use `getClass().getResource(path)` construction.

Relative paths:

1. If your resource is in 'root' of resource dir your path should starts with `/`:

   `"/etc.txt"`

   Where file etc.txt stored in resources directory.

For your example in picture your path would be: `/queries/storedQueries.txt`

2. If your resources is in resource directory, but in flatten directories, same as packages for class which you invoke `.getResource(path)`, like:

`resources/com/pe/queries/etc.txt`

Your path should not include started '/':
`getClass().getResource("com/pe/queries/etc.txt")`

This is because when your build system(your maven) will build project it put your resource in 'root' of jar if you store it in `root` of resources directory, or, if you store like `resources/com/pe/queries/etc.txt`, creates inside jar `com/pe/queries/` and put it inside.

Sorry for my English, hope i help you to understand how it works.

P.S. I wrote this article, it's on Russian, but you can translate it by Google-transate(i tried and it's understandable), there is more examples and explanations inside.

[Article about resources on Russian](https://github.com/qcha/JBook/blob/master/build/resources.md)

Good luck!